# On the solutions of an equation involving the Euler's totient function that is solved by the primes of Rassias' conjecture

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function, experimental-mathematics

Here $\varphi(n)$ denotes the Euler's totient function. I've deduced a family of prime numbers $$(x=p_1,y=p_2)$$ that solve an equation involving the Euler's totient function. These primes are the prime numbers that appear in the Rassias' conjecture, see this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rassias%27_conjecture), since I've created this equation on assumption of this conjecture with this purpose. Now I try to find different sets of positive integers being solution of the equation that I present.

**Claim.** Let $k\geq 1$ a fixed integer. On assumption of the Rassias' conjecture one has that there exist infinitely many solutions of the equation $$\varphi\left(\left(x+y+1\right)^k\right)=\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)(y+1)\left(x+y+1\right)^{k-1}\tag{1}$$
with $x<y$ prime numbers .

> **Question.**  Can you find a different infinite family of integer solutions, $1<u<v$ not being both prime numbers
>   $$\varphi\left(\left(u+v+1\right)^\kappa\right)=\left(1-\frac{1}{u}\right)(v+1)\left(u+v+1\right)^{\kappa-1},$$
>   for a suitable $\kappa>1$ fixed integer? **Many thanks.**

If it is very difficult but you've computational evidence, feel free to add this evidence of the existence of such set of solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An infinite family of solutions is given by:
$$(u,v)=(p,pq-p-1)$$
where $p$ and $q$ are different primes numbers.

---

**Proof**
\begin{align*}
\varphi((u+v+1)^\kappa) &=\varphi(p^\kappa q^\kappa)\\
&=\varphi(p^\kappa)\varphi(q^\kappa)\\
&=(p-1)(q-1)(pq)^{\kappa-1}\\
&=(u-1)\cdot\frac{v+1}{u}(v+u+1)^{\kappa-1}\\
&=\left(1-\frac1u\right)(v+1)(v+u+1)^{\kappa-1}
\end{align*}

Comment: Now I'm stuck with the fourth identiy, but tomorrow I check it. Many thanks. Also I am going to wait if there are more answers, but I should accept yours as right